# Unable to install poppler module in anaconda

Tags: python, package, qt5, ocr, poppler

I'm trying to follow the following this [tutorial](https://datascience.blog.wzb.eu/2017/02/16/data-mining-ocr-pdfs-using-pdftabextract-to-liberate-tabular-data-from-scanned-documents/) by executing the `pdftohtml` command from poppler-utils to extract the texts and scanned images from the PDF.

I've downloaded the poppler from [here](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) by downloading both the latest stable release poppler-0.83.0.tar.xz, released on November 27, 2019 and poppler encoding data poppler-data-0.4.9.tar.gz, released on April 24, 2018 and extracted both of them, placing them in my anaconda package path but for some reasons, jupyter notebook is unable to detect "pdftohtml" module.

I've also tried to install via

```
pip install python-poppler-qt5
```

but to no avail. What am I doing wrong here or is there any workaround this?